# Declarative way to extend/concatenate multiple ListModel

Tags: qt, qml

I want to build multiple `ListModel` that will all start with common elements.
I want to fill the remaining elements from another `ListModel`.

Example :
ListModel (1) :

```
COMMON A
COMMON B
COMMON C
A1
B1
C1
```

ListModel (2) :

```
COMMON A
COMMON B
COMMON C
A2
B2
C2
```

Is there a way to declaratively "merge" or extend two `ListModel`?

So far I am doing it dynamically:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    width: 480
    height: 320
    visible: true

    ListModel {
        id: commonModel
        ListElement { value: "COMMON A" }
        ListElement { value: "COMMON B" }
        ListElement { value: "COMMON C" }
    }

    ListModel {
        id: model1
        ListElement { value: "A1" }
        ListElement { value: "B1" }
        ListElement { value: "C1" }
    }

    ListModel {
        id: model2
        ListElement { value: "A2" }
        ListElement { value: "B2" }
        ListElement { value: "C2" }
    }

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: commonModel // here I would like to directly specify the "concatenated" model

        delegate: Text { text: model.value}

        // dynamic part that I want to avoid
        readonly property var additionalModel: model2
        Component.onCompleted: {
            for (var i = 0; i < additionalModel.count; ++i) {
                var elt = additionalModel.get(i)
                model.append(elt)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Edit: In other words, I would like to do something as simple as this :

```
// MyModel.qml
ListModel {
    ListElement { value: "COMMON A" }
    ListElement { value: "COMMON B" }
    ListElement { value: "COMMON C" }
}
```

Being able to extend it as needed in another component:

```
ListView {
    model: MyModel {
        // keep original elements from MyModel and add custom "component-related" elements
        ListElement { value: "OTHER A" }
        ListElement { value: "OTHER B" }
        ListElement { value: "OTHER C" }
    }
}
```

But it does not seem possible since I obtain the following error:

> Cannot assign to non-existent default property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's begin with patching the error. It comes from here:

```
model: MyModel {
    ListElement { role_value: "OTHER A" }
    ListElement { role_value: "OTHER B" }
    ListElement { role_value: "OTHER C" }
}
```

To get this sort of behaviour, you'll need to set one of the properties of `MyModel` to a [`default` property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#default-properties). Trivially, something like

```
//  MyModel.qml
ListModel {
    default property list<ListElement> otherModels

    ListElement { role_value: "COMMON A" }
    ListElement { role_value: "COMMON B" }
    ListElement { role_value: "COMMON C" }
}

//  Main.qml
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    ListView {
        model: MyModel {
            // these should be auto-assigned to the default property      
            ListElement { role_value: "OTHER A" }
            ListElement { role_value: "OTHER B" }
            ListElement { role_value: "OTHER C" }
        }
    }
}
```

Normally, with other types, this would work fine. But `ListElement` is a special case. If you try running the above, you'd probably get an error:

> Cannot assign to non-existent property "role_value"

[Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listelement.html) hints that `ListElements` can only be defined under `ListModels`. As far as I know, that seems to be the only feasible workaround. This means changing the default property to `list<ListModel>` and changing the usage to

```
ListView {
    model: MyModel {
        // ListModel is auto-assigned to the default property
        ListModel {
            ListElement { role_value: "OTHER A" }
            ListElement { role_value: "OTHER B" }
            ListElement { role_value: "OTHER C" }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a minimal and complete example:

```
//  MyModel.qml
import QtQuick 2.0

ListModel {
    id: model
    default property list<ListModel> otherModels

    ListElement { role_value: "COMMON A" }
    ListElement { role_value: "COMMON B" }
    ListElement { role_value: "COMMON C" }

    //  called everytime a model is append to otherModels
    onOtherModelsChanged: {
        //  add ListElements from the last otherModels to this model
        var i = otherModels.length - 1;
        if (i < 0) return;

        for (var j = 0; j < otherModels[i].count; j++)
            model.append(otherModels[i].get(j));
    }
}


//  Main.qml
import QtQuick 2.6 
import QtQuick.Window 2.2      //  Window
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2    //  ItemDelegate

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: MyModel {
            ListModel {
                ListElement { role_value: "OTHER A" }
                ListElement { role_value: "OTHER B" }
                ListElement { role_value: "OTHER C" }
            }
        }

        delegate: ItemDelegate {
            text: role_value
            width: parent.width
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>[*See a more sophisticated demo on Github.*](https://github.com/TrebledJ/Qt-Examples/tree/master/%5Bqml%5D--model-concatenation)</sup>

`default property list<ListModel>` and the implementation of `onOtherModelsChanged` allows multiple models to be "concatenated" onto the base model.

Screenshot of Success:

[image]

As noted by [augre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4503757/augre), in the case where only ***one*** model is ever concatenated, you can simplify the property to `default property ListModel otherModel` and have

```
onOtherModelChanged: {
    if (otherModel === undefined) return;
    for (var i = 0; i < otherModel.count; i++)
        model.append(otherModel.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Exactly the kind of workaround I was trying to achieve! Very nice use of the default property. Thanks :)

Comment: Note that I don't have to use a `list<ListModel>` default property. The same behavior is possible using only a `default property ListModel`, and then it also simplifies the addition of the next elements: `model.append(otherModels.get(j))`

Comment: Also, I realize this allows to create multiple chained `ListModel` components, each of them adding its own `ListElement`s to the model, allowing to keep extending the model in another subcomponent. Very nice!

Comment: Mm... yeah, you could do `default property ListModel`. That'd work for adding one model. "_I realize this allows to create multiple chained ListModel components_" Haha, yeah I tested to see if that'd work (also on the github demo). Maybe my answer needs some more explanation